# Primavera V10, Extensibilidade, como usar a função: this.ContextService.ArtigoPrecos.GetEdita(dynamic Index)

Tags: c#

No Primavera V10, na API Extensibilidade:

1. Tenho um CustomTab na "Ficha de Artigo"
2. Preciso de aceder ao artigo/moeda atualmente a ser editada na ficha.
3. Utilizo a instrução: `MessageBox.Show(this.ContextService.ArtigoPrecos.NumItens.ToString());`para detectar quantos itens existem e relata 1 item que corresponde à moeda sendo editada

Como posso utilizar a instrucção: `this.ContextService.ArtigoPrecos.GetEdita(dynamic Index)`
   para obter o objecto do tipo `BasBEArtigoMoeda`?

Atualmente para obter estes dados a partir da base de dados utilizo:

```
BasBEArtigoMoeda artigoMoeda this.ContextService.BSO.Base.ArtigosPrecos.Edita(
    this.ContextService.Artigo.Artigo, 
    this.ContextService.BSO.Contexto.MoedaBase,
    this.ContextService.Artigo.UnidadeVenda);
```

Comment: this.ContextService.ArtigoPrecos.GetEdita(1) devolve a primeira moeda a ser editada

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia,

A manipulação destes valores na ficha do artigo, a partir dum separador de utilizador, pode ser feita da seguinte forma:

```
if (this.ContextService.ArtigoPrecos != null)
{
    BasBEArtigoMoeda precos = this.ContextService.ArtigoPrecos.First(p => (p.Moeda == this.ContextService.BSO.Contexto.MoedaBase) && (p.Unidade == this.ContextService.Artigo.UnidadeVenda));

    if (precos != null)
    {
        precos.PVP1 = 2.2;
        this.ContextService.CommitContext();
    }
}
```

É importante que a instrução `this.ContextService.CommitContext()` seja invocada no final de forma a que os valores na ficha sejam atualizados.

Comment: O código: BasBEArtigoMoeda precos = this.ContextService.ArtigoPrecos.First(p => (p.Moeda == this.ContextService.BSO.Contexto.MoedaBase) && (p.Unidade == this.ContextService.Artigo.UnidadeVenda)); Dá erro "Erro ao carregar o registo na extensibilidade"

Comment: Experimanta colocar o seguinte antes do if: this.ContextService.RefreshContext();

Comment: Optei por fazer validações extras no UIFichaArtigo para os eventos que vão influenciar o carregar de dados.